# SELinux Error is Preventing me from Logging into a GCE VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, centos, google-compute-engine, gcloud, selinux

I am unable to SSH into a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Google Compute Engine (GCE) instance running CentOS 7 with the Cloud SDK CLI (`gcloud`).

When I try to SSH into the GCE VM using the GCP Cloud Shell, the following error appears:

```shell
[!!!!!!] Failed to load SELinux policy, freezing
```

How would I solve this for a VM running in GCE?

Comment: it's solved, by tutorial edit SELinux from booting using GCP cloud shell

Comment: Great news!  You _could_ post this, with supporting details, as an answer and then accept it.